# Manipulate colours on ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

I want to build a `qplot` using this library.

I have a dataset

```
Head(data) 

tstamp                 elementid     value      hours
2016-09-15 15:20:28    IN_TEMP       24.99558   15
2016-09-15 15:20:28    IN_TEMP       25.12237   15
2016-09-15 15:20:29    IN_TEMP       25.44952   15
2016-09-15 15:20:29    IN_TEMP       25.53550   15
2016-09-15 15:20:39    IN_PRESSURE   101.40683  15
2016-09-15 15:20:49    IN_TEMP       25.94596   15
```

and I created my `qplot`

```
qplot(data = data, y = value, log = "xy", color = elementid ,facets = hours~elementid)
```

[image]

But now I am trying to manipulate the plot.

for example:

I want the "IN_TEMP" div on the left side of the graph
and I want swap the colours of the points (blue become red and red become blue)

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can create elementid as an ordered factor, R automatically sorts the factor levels alphabetically but you can use the ?factor order like this.

```
    elementid  <- factor(elementid , levels=c("IN_TEMP","IN_PRESSURE"), ordered=TRUE)
```

That should solve both your colours and your plot order problem.

Comment: It works thanks :)
i tried something similar but whitout the "ordered = TRUE"
that was my problem :)
Thanks a lot